# How to send an id of a cell to controller in Spring-boot

Tags: html, jsp, spring-boot

What is the best way to send an id of cell of a table to controller, when I click on cell ? I tried with Ajax ,but it gives me `403 post error` and I couldn't solve it .
When I click on a cell, content() function is activated, but I don't know how to send id of this cell to controller, my goal is to send id to controller and then in database(Mysql) change the state of that spesific element to `true` and come back to jsp.

This is my model

```
@Entity 
public class Room {
    private int id;
    private String  hour1;
    private boolean hour1confirm;
    private String  hour2;
    private boolean hour2confirm;
    private String  hour3;
    private boolean hour3confirm;
    private String  hour4;
    private boolean hour4confirm;
    private String  hour5;
    private boolean hour5confirm;
    private String  day;
```

and this is my jsp

```
<body>

<div class="container" align="center">
          <table  class="table table-bordered" >
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>\Days \Hours</th>  <th>8 - 10</th>   
                  <th >10 - 12</th> <th >12 - 14</th> 
                  <th >14 - 16</th> <th >16 - 18</th> 
                </tr>
             </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items= "${rooms2}" var="m" >
                    <tr>
                     <td style="background-color:OldLace">${m.day }</td>
                     <c:choose>
                         <c:when test="${m.hour1confirm==false}">
                           <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour1}"  onclick="content1(this)" >${m.hour1 }</td>
                           </c:when>
                          <c:otherwise> <td style="background-color:red"> Reserved</td> </c:otherwise>
                           </c:choose>

                           <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${m.hour2confirm==false}">
                               <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour2 }" onclick="content1(this)">${m.hour2 } </td>
                             </c:when>
                             <c:otherwise> <td style="background-color:red"> Reserved</td> </c:otherwise>
                             </c:choose>

                              <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${m.hour3confirm==false}">
                                  <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour3 }" onclick="content1(this)">${m.hour3 } </td>
                                </c:when>
                              <c:otherwise> <td style="background-color:red"> Reserved</td> </c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>

                              <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${m.hour4confirm==false}">
                                  <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour4 }" onclick="content1(this)">${m.hour4 } </td>
                                </c:when>
                              <c:otherwise> <td style="background-color:red"> Reserved</td> </c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>

                              <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${m.hour5confirm==false}">
                                  <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour5 }" onclick="content1(this)">${m.hour5 } </td>
                                </c:when>
                              <c:otherwise> <td style="background-color:red"> Reserved</td> </c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>


                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
          </table>
<br>
</div>
<br>


</body> 
<script >

var idt;
function content1(elem)
   {
    $(function() {
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            if (options.type == "POST") {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            }
        });
    });
         idt=elem.id;
             $.ajax({

             url:"/reservation2",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  idt,             
                    dataType: "text",          
                    contentType: "text/plain",
                   // mimeType: false,
                    success: function(response){ 
                        console.log(data);              
                        return false;     
                    } 
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer,so I share it here.I could do this with Get and not Post ,in my jsp I use

```
$.ajax
    ({  method : 'GET',
        url : 'reservationTest?room_id='+id})
```

and in controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reservationTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)   
    public void reservationAjax(HttpServletRequest req) 
    {
            //String id = req.getParameter("room_id");
            String id = req.getParameter("room_id");
.
.
.
```

Comment: I wouldnt recommend changing your database through a GET request. If you dont have any custom security enabled I guess the 403 http response you encountered for your POST is because of CORS settings. Please check the docs: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/